# How do I test a schedulable email sending?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, singleemailmessage

I have a schedulable apex class for the email sending. I tested a schedule, but I can't to coverage sending logic. Is there a some way to test good and bad scenarios for it?

My class:

```
public class EmailSchedule implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(System.SchedulableContext ctx){
        List<Tool__c> toolsForEmail = [SELECT Email__c, Email_content__c FROM Tool__c LIMIT 10];
        List<Tool__c> toolsToUpdateEmail = new List<Tool__c>();

        if(!toolsForEmail.isEmpty()){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
            for(Tool__c toolEmail : toolsForEmail){
                 if(toolEmail.Email__c != null && toolEmail.Email_content__c != null){                    
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {toolEmail.Email__c};
                    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                    mail.setReplyTo('tool@gmail.com');                   
                    mail.setPlainTextBody(toolEmail.Email_content__c);
                    messages.add(mail);
                    toolsToUpdateEmailStatus.add(toolEmail);
                }
            }
            Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
            if(!toolsToUpdateEmailStatus.isEmpty()){
                update toolsToUpdateEmail; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@isTest
public class EmailScheduleTest {
    @isTest static void testSchedule(){
        test.starttest();
            EmailCheckInSchedule myClass = new EmailCheckInSchedule();   
            String chron = '0 0 10 * * ?';        
            System.schedule('Test Sched', chron, myClass);
        test.stopTest(); 
    }

    @isTest static void sendEmail(){
        Tool__c tool = new Tool__c(
            Name = 'Test',
            Email__c = 'test@test.com',
            Email_content__c = 'Test email content'
        );

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {tool.Email__c, 'test2@test.com'};
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setReplyTo('tool@gmail.com');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(tool.Email_content__c);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.Email>{mail});
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue are you facing? You have not even define records for object `Tool__c` in your test class.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. Updated it. But still no coverage.

Comment: In the method ‘sendemail’ you’re not calling schedular. Also starttest and stoptest are missing. Hence it won’t work. Refer Salesforce trailhead for apex testing.

Comment: I read and even finished that trailheads. But there are no good examples for schedule + emailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer below Test class. I've modified a bit and invoked Schedular:

```
@isTest
public class EmailScheduleTest {

    @isTest static void sendEmail(){
        List<Tool__c> lstTool = new List <Tool__c> ();
        Tool__c tool = new Tool__c(
            Name = 'Test',
            Email__c = 'test@test.com',
            Email_content__c = 'Test email content'
        );
        lstTool.add (tool);
        tool = new Tool__c(
            Name = 'Test_2',
            Email__c = 'test@best.com',
            Email_content__c = 'Best email content'
        );
        lstTool.add (tool);
        insert lstTool;

        test.startTest ();
        EmailSchedule myClass = new EmailSchedule();   
        String chron = '0 0 10 * * ?';        
        System.schedule('Test Sched', chron, myClass);
        test.stopTest ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I forgot to insert the record :)